# Can an image be added to each item in a PayPal Cart?

Tags: image, paypal

I am using a simple cart with an "Add to Cart" button.  I would like to add an image along with the description of each item placed in the PayPal cart.  I have tried placing an image url in the value field of the variable item_number.  But nothing I trying seems to fool PayPal and I can not find a PayPal variable that allows the insertion of a item image.

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions?
Here is part of the code that I used in the Add to Cart Button code:

Comment: Please include a relevant snippet from the code you tried.

Comment: Here is the button code:  <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <br><input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0">
     
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="YLI #100 Silk Thread [201 - Bright Red]">
     <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="http://www.clickerflicker.com/Graphics/20210201.jpg">
     <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.60">
     <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="2.41">
     <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">
</form>

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear before. I meant that you should edit your question to include that code.